# Scout Eclipse tree navigation without table page

Tags: outline, tree-structure, eclipse-scout

I know that in Scout you can do tree hierarchy in Outline, but you get table page in right side with rows corresponding tree hierarchy. 
Like : My Contacts in [large example](http://tools.bsiag.com/scoutbook/3.9/latest/html/bookch6.html)

But what I want is same tree structure on left (Outline) side, without corresponding table page on right (main) side.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

If you make AbstractExtensiblePageWithNodes you have check box Table Visible. All it's needed is set this to false.